# Placeholder form attribute causing responsive design to break when switching orientation

Tags: forms, responsive-design, placeholder

Going to try my best to explain this as I don't have a working example at the moment.

I've found now with two sites, both using twitter bootstrap as a framework, an odd occurrence regarding the form placeholder element.

Take this theme for example, and note the newsletter form in the footer.
[Theme](http://octavus.html.themewoodmen.com)

It uses the placeholder form attribute to label the name and email elements.

Now when viewing on an iPad/iPhone these display fine. Switch the orientation, and it will adjust fine, but then switch the orientation back, (i.e. portrait>landscape>portrait) and it throws the page off and knocks it off to the left. The layout is no longer fixed to the width.

I cannot understand why this is?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with iOS6, resolved in iOS7. Setting `overflow: hidden;` on the parent element of the input element (for example the form) fixes the problem.